# Android: Не запускается активити из сервиса

Tags: activity, android, java

Есть активити. При переходе её в паузу (блокировка экрана, сворачивание, закрытие) запускается сервис, который открывает активити (эту же или какую нибудь другую, не важно) через некоторое время. Но при этом это работает как то через раз. Например при отладке в логкет, всё всегда работает идеально, поэтому найти источник ошибки не могу. Но при это этом когда берёшь телефон на живой тест, то "звонок" (вызов активити из сервиса) практически никогда не срабатывает.

Ах да, ещё. В активити прописано снятие блокировки и пробуждение экрана:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение найдено! Спасибо огромное [[@Heisenberg](/users/22290/heisenberg)](/users/22290/heisenberg), которых направил меня в правильную сторону размышлений )

Дело в том что андроид после блокировки экрана оправляется в "спячку", в процессе которой могут не работать многие функции из сервиса.

Решение очень простое - нужно было снести нафиг этот сервис и использовать pendingIntent с alarmManager для запуска активити. В AlarmManager можно указать такой параметр при выставлении времени как Wakeup - что и есть пробуждение после "спячки".

Answer (score 5):

Дело тут не в запуске активности( ведь вы, разумеется, уверены в валидности контекста, в котором запускаете активность? ), а в том, как и когда **действительно** происходит запуск сервиса.

Вот, вы говорите, что сервис стартует при инвалидации активности. Каким методом-обработчиком вы пользуетесь( onPause, onStop, onDestroy:) )?

---

Также, вы написали, что при отладке посредством LogCat не было замечено неисправностей.
Наверняка, устройство при этом было подключено по USB? Если да, то оно имело источник заряда. В таком случае Android особо не экономит ресурсы, а потому реже происходят срабатывания различных техник понижения транжира доступного заряда( вроде LowMemory ).
В случае же отсутствия источника, Android урезает все, что только можно, чтобы сэконимть зяряд.

Так что, ваша проблема может зависеть от нескольких факторов.

---

**UPD**

Попробуйте обрабатывать также метод onStop(). Т.е при выходе из активного состояния( onPause ) и выходе из видимого состояния( onStop ) запускайте сервис.

Comment: Обработчик я уже писал - onPause() (пауза)
Устройство было подключено по usb, верно. Сейчас проверил, да, когда подключаешь телефон к зарядке, начинает всё работать. Возникает вопрос, что же тут делать?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Увы, проблема наверное не здесь. Сервис всегда нормально стартует. Всё работает если экран не блокировать. Если же блокировать телефон, то работает только при подключенной зарядке. (но сервис стартует всё равно)

Comment: Думаю, в таком случае вам подойдет использование широковещательных приемников. Зарегистрируйте приемник, обрабатывающий системное событие ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. В методе onReceive() запускайте серсис.

Comment: Но как это мне поможет, если сервис и так запускается? Не работает же только запуск активити.